# Rudin's proof of invariant subspace existence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I have questions about Rudin's proof of invariant subspace existence.

On page 327, point 12.27,

1. How does he get that $Tx=TE(\omega)x$, and
2. How does he know $E(\omega)$ is not the zero map?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a typo. The second $x$ should be a different letter.
   Since $x\in M=\mathrm{im}\,E(\omega)$, there is a $y\in H$ such that $E(\omega)y=x$. Therefore
   $$Tx=TE(\omega)y=E(\omega)Ty$$
   so $Tx\in M$.
2. It is possible that $E(\omega)=0$, but the point is that there *exists* $\omega$ such that $E(\omega)\not=0$, because otherwise $E(\omega)=0$ for all Borel sets $\omega$ and therefore

$$T=\int_{\sigma(T)} \lambda\,dE(\lambda)=0$$

Comment: Thinking about it, how do we know there is a partition of the spectrum? Also, we need to gurantee that  both sets of the partition are such that E(.) is not the zero operator. Thanks

Comment: Given any Borel set $\omega$, $\omega^\prime=\Delta\backslash\omega$ is also Borel and we have $\omega\cup \omega^\prime=\Delta$. Also: why would we need that $E(\omega^\prime)$ is also non-zero?

Comment: I suppose we don't except that all proofs that I have seen stipulate that both sets have non-zero measure